# Best practices (unit) testing Windows Azure

Tags: unit-testing, azure

Within a short-time period I'm going to start a project based on Windows Azure. And I was wondering what are the experiences with testing for Windows Azure projects (in continuous intergration (with a TFS build server))? (Eventual using TDD)

Some things I was wondering:

- Do you use mocking (in your own written wrapper class)?
- Do you use the storage emulator?
- Do you deploy the services to Azure and run the tests from the build server to the cloud? (what about costs)?

Thnaks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same good practices for writing unit tests for applications outside of Windows Azure apply.  If you have an external dependency to what you are actually testing, that dependency should be mocked and injected for your granular unit test.

For example, when I'm using Windows Azure Storage Queues I will have an interface that I use to interact with the queue itself, so in my code consuming the queue service I can mock the subsystem using the interface and use dependency injection to inject the mock.  This removes the necessity to actually deal with the emulator during unit tests.  For the most part the actual concrete implementation of the code working with the queue is not much more than a very thin wrapper.

I personally don't shoot for 100% test coverage, so I may not have direct unit tests that utilize the concrete implementation of the wrappers.  In many cases I try to have integration tests that will exercise these wrappers and exercise multiple aspects of the system working together.  In some cases I can run the integration tests in the emulator (for Storage operations for example), but in some cases they simply have to be run with access to the Windows Azure environment (in the case of usage of ACS or Service Bus).

Ideally you'd like to have a set of scripts that can be run to spin up a minimum set of test servers in Azure, deploy your solution and exercise the integration tests that can't be done on premises.  Then get the results of that and have the script shut everything down (or optionally leave it running if you need that).  Then run the integration tests suite that utilizes these scripts often enough to detect issues, but you certainly don't need to run them every time you check something in unless you are happy with running the test environment all the time.  If you okay with the cost of a semi-permanent test environment running in Azure then just make sure to have the scripts to an update deployment rather than a delete and redeploy to cut down on cost a bit (savings would be relative to how often the deploy occurs).

I believe this question is a very subjective one as you're likely to get several different opinions.

Comment: I want several opinions, so I can see which different options there are and which 'best-practices' there are (which can differ per answer)